# Int32 parse not finding object in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have the follow asp file:

```
<H3>test file</H3>
<%
s = "1"
a = Int32.Parse(s)
%>
```

and I get the following error:

```
test file
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
Object required: ''
/ignore/testInt32.asp, line 4
```

I suspect I am missing an include, but I can not find any example that has an include.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using classic asp. I looked this up because I though

```
Int32.Parse()
```

was a bit strange. As far as I can tell that is a ASP.NET only function. for classic asp you should use

```
CInt()
```

**Edit:** Just wanted to update my answer a bit. While the above line would give you no issue in your example, in order to make sure the code exactly matches what your original code would do, you should instead use

```
CLng()
```

CLng will overflow after ~2 million the same as Int32. CInt on the other hand CInt will overflow after ~30k. Either way for classic asp you should use one of those two.

Comment: That was the problem, I did not realize that Int32.Parse was not classic asp.

Comment: `Parse()` is not a "function" as such, it is a method of the `System.Int32` structure. @Alastar If you use any of the conversion functions `CInt()`, `CLng()` etc, remember to check before hand they contain valid data as VBScript is *typeless* it is easy to encounter conversion errors.

Answer (score 1):

### Why did you get an `Object Required` Error?

The issue is your mixing [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) objects with [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) which out of the box Classic ASP (by default [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript)) doesn't know about.

The fact a line number is included should lead to the cause of the problem fairly quickly.

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
Object required: ''
/ignore/testInt32.asp, line 4
```

on line 4 which will be;

```vb
a = Int32.Parse(s)
```

An Object is required error occurs because `Int32` is not a valid "Object Reference" as far as VBScript is concerned. There is no built-in Objects called `Int32` and there is no instantiation of an `Int32` Object Reference using code like;

```vb
Set Int32 = Server.CreateObject("TheObjectsProgID")
```

### Solution

If you want to parse an Long data type in VBScript as [@KHeaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915817/kheaney) [has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27048527/692942) you should be using

```vb
a = CLng(s)
```

### VBScript is Typeless so Check Your Variables

Be aware that if the value of `s` is not a valid numeric value you conversion will fail and you will receive a

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '0x800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'CLng'
```

There are various ways to get around this including using `Val()` which will return non numeric conversions as `0` (this can be dangerous). Another approach is to check the value beforehand using something like;

```vb
If IsNumeric(s) Then a = CLng(s) Else a = 0
```

You don't have to set `a = 0` this can be any assignment `a = ""` is also possible, the fact is checking the variable like this gives you greater control over the outcome.

---

### Useful Links

- [CLng() Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
- [VBScript Data Types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee198856.aspx)

Comment: Errors that say '' is not an object, are NOT self explanatory.  If it had said 'Int32' is not an object, when what you said would make sense.

Comment: @Alastar No offence but it tells you the line number which then points you to the object, admittedly it would be more helpful if it said `Object Required: 'Int32'` but it still points you to the Object Reference *(via the line number)* which in this case is `Int32`. Hopefully my answer has helped you understand the reason for the error and how to diagnose it in the future.